# How to avoid getting twice the same answer?

Tags: prolog

I have this little piece of code here:

```
axe(_, 0, 0).
axe(0, _, 0).
axe(0, 0, _).
```

On input `?- axe(0, 0, X).` I get the following result:

```
X = 0 ; no
X = 0 ; no
true.
```

How do I prevent getting twice the same answer ? This is obviously wrong.

Comment: The main point to understand about this example is that it is *not* "wrong"! You simply get a solution redundantly! So, this is not a question about correctness.

Comment: It isn't really "wrong" based upon the facts you have provided. It's only "wrong" if you did not intend to have overlapping solutions. Prolog will find *every* solution option. In your case, your facts present 3 ways in which `axe(0, 0, X)` succeeds. Two different ways with `X = 0` and one in which any value of `X` will cause it to succeed (thus the final `true`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this code, Prolog does the backtracking and try to find another solution for your query. If finds with the first rule that it works if X = 0. Then, with the second rule, it also founds out that it's true if X = 0. As such, you can make sure to cancel any further check by specifying that X should not be equal to 0 because it was checked in the previous clase. You can do it this way :

```
axe(_,0,0).
axe(0,X,0) :- X \== 0.
axe(0,0,X) :- X \== 0.
```

Hope it helps !